# Ola Hallengren: encrypt, but verify?

Tags: sql-server, backup, encryption, sql-server-2017, ola-hallengren

I've been using Ola Hallengren's scripts for a few years now, and a recent upgrade to MSSQL2017 has allowed me to start testing encrypted back-ups. Before anyone asks: yes, master keys and encryption certificates have been backed up and stored in our password manager.

I'm running into an issue with the following parameter combination:

```
EXECUTE [OlaHallengren].[DatabaseBackup]
     @Databases = 'SYSTEM_DATABASES'
    ,@Directory = N'\\<SHARE>\SQLBackup\Daily'
    ,@BackupType = 'FULL'
    ,@Verify = 'Y'
    ,@CheckSum = 'Y'
    ,@Encrypt = 'Y'
    ,@EncryptionAlgorithm = 'AES_256'
    ,@ServerCertificate = 'DBBackupEncryptCert<SERVERNAME>'
    ,@LogToTable = 'Y'
```

The back-up runs fine, but verification does not:

```
Command: RESTORE VERIFYONLY FROM DISK = N'\\<SHARE>\SQLBackup\Daily\<SERVER>\master\FULL\...
Process Exit Code 1.
The step failed.
```

It seems to be an issue with Ola Hallengren's script not being able to open the master key, because this doesn't work:

```
RESTORE VERIFYONLY FROM DISK = N'\\<SHARE>\SQLBackup\Daily\<SERVER>\master\FULL\<SERVER>_master_FULL_<DATE>_<TIME>.bak'
```

but this does:

```
use master;
OPEN MASTER KEY DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = '<PASSWORD>';

RESTORE VERIFYONLY FROM DISK = N'\\<SHARE>\SQLBackup\Daily\<SERVER>\master\FULL\<SERVER>_master_FULL_<DATE>_<TIME>.bak'

CLOSE MASTER KEY
```

Am I trying to have my cake and eat it, too?
Or is there a way to have both encryption and verification with Ola's scripts?

Comment: Ola has his scripts on [GitHub](https://github.com/olahallengren/sql-server-maintenance-solution). If you'd like to request this as a feature, that's the best place to do it.

Comment: That's why I posted here first. I didn't see anything in the docs there saying "you can't verify if you encrypt", so I hoped I was making a mistake.

Comment: Gotcha. Yeah, it may be an oversight in the docs. Looking through the code, I don't see anything that checks for encryption when the verify string is built up.

Answer (score 5):

I've found the root cause and solution.

Ola Hallengren couldn't get to the back-up encryption certificate because doesn't know the Database Master Key (DMK) encryption password. The DMK can also be encrypted using the Service Master Key (SMK), which is automatically opened for a connection with sufficient privileges.

I've added SMK encryption to the DMK, which allows Ola's scripts to access the back-up encryption certificate.

I guess it only works if it's turtles all the way down. :-P